# Macro to delete empty columns deletes all columns regardless of content

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

How do I tell my Macro to delete only the columns without data, reading from row two downwards.

My situation:

I generate reports from an external tool which then populates based on tags within my tables. There are three columns which I care about: "Name", which is always populated, "Age", which is sometimes empty and "Output" which is often empty (I do not yet have the reputation to post images for visual support).

My Macro currently deletes both the "Output" and "Age" columns, regardless of whether or not there is data in the fields.

The Macro in its current form:

```
Sub ColumnDelete()
    Dim Tbl As Table, cel As Cell, i As Long, fEmpty As Boolean
    With ActiveDocument
        For Each Tbl In .Tables
            For i = Tbl.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
                fEmpty = False
                For Each cel In Tbl.Columns(i).Cells
                    If cel.Range.Text = "Output" & Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
                        fEmpty = True
                    End If
                    If cel.Range.Text = "Age" & Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
                        fEmpty = True
                    End If
                Exit For
                Next cel
                If fEmpty = True Then Tbl.Columns(i).Delete
            Next i
        Next Tbl
    End With
    Set cel = Nothing: Set Tbl = Nothing
End Sub
```

I thought that combining "Output" and the empty table characters would work, but in practice it appears I'm wrong. Removing "Output" from the script results in no action at all.
e.g.

```
If cel.Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
```

And combining both "Output" and "Age" in one "If" loop results in the "13" error.

Comment: I see the issue... as a test, make your last column empty, then if you step thru the code manually, you will note it does NOT check a Cel if it is empty - it skips it. Therefore, you need to add a counter for rows and when finished compare to 'tbl.Rows.Count' - if your counter is zero (or 1 if you have a header as row 1), then the column is empty. I can post code if you need.

Comment: ooops! Hold that last comment... why do you have the 'Exit For' in the loop???

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn I inherited the code, and being a complete novice with VBA, have been tinkering around. As to the "Exit For", I guessed that was to end the For loop in the same way as the "End If", and the "Next cel" repeats that loop.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn, I just removed the "Exit For" and the "Output" table is still blindly deleted as before. Some example code would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will look thru a table, then examine a column to see if any value is in any row other than the first. If nothing is found, the column will be deleted.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ColumnDelete()
    Dim Tbl As Table, cel As Cell, i As Long, fEmpty As Boolean

    With ActiveDocument
        For Each Tbl In .Tables
            'Debug.Print "--------------------------"
            For i = Tbl.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
                'Debug.Print "Col: " & i
                fEmpty = True
                For Each cel In Tbl.Columns(i).Cells
                    'Debug.Print cel.Range.Text
                    If (cel.Range.Text <> Chr(13) & Chr(7)) And cel.Row.Index > 1 Then
                        fEmpty = False
                    End If
                'Exit For
                Next cel
                If fEmpty = True Then
                    'Debug.Print "Delete Col: " & i
                    Tbl.Columns(i).Delete
                End If
            Next i
        Next Tbl
    End With
    Set cel = Nothing: Set Tbl = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I cannot up-vote at the moment, but it's very appreciated!